# Good A, better B?

Tags: comparatives, ellipses

If I want to say a line meaning

> John is a good husband. And he is even better as a father.

is it correct to lose ‘even’ and ‘as’? So the sentences will be like

> 1) John is a good husband. And better as a father.
>
> 2) John is a good husband. Even better a father.
>
> 3) John is a good husband. Better a father.

Is any of these sentences grammatically right, and will the meaning stay the same?

Comment: *Even* is an intensifier in your context. Taking it out of the original quote doesn't change the grammar. However, your alternative #3 isn't strictly equivalent. The second sentence can be read as treating the first as something of a backhanded compliment.

Comment: 1. Is the best here, but not quite parallel: “John is a good husband and an even better father.”

Comment: Consider "John is a good husband and better father." In your three examples, the second "sentences" are not sentences. They lack verbs.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes.

But, first of all, none of your second set of three sentences are grammatically correct for other reasons.  The first is missing a comma.  The others are fragments missing a noun.  In speaking, people do this.  But, in writing, you need to avoid it usually.  Now, some writers get away with it, but, it is not correct.  (You're asking if it is correct.)

As to what you care about, the use of "even" is not needed because "better" serves the same purpose.  What's the purpose?  Both words reduce the thought required to comprehend what you are trying to communicate.  Logically, we can determine what you mean, but in English it is important to do it using words like "even" or "better."  Here, it is correct to simply say,

```
John is a good husband, but a better father.
John is a good husband and a great father.
John is a good husband and an even better father.
```

The use of "as" is not only not needed but is inhumane (considering a person as a tool, like a hammer or something).

Answer (score 0):

You could say: John is a better father than a husband, but I suppose that has a negative implication. So, how about; John is a good husband and a better father.
Or, John is a good husband and an excellent father. John is a good husband but as a father he is the best. Finally, John is a good husband and a very good father.

Answer (score 0):

I think the line you want is "John is a good husband, and a better father".